# Allowing non-schema values during WFT transaction between OpenLayers and GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wfs, wfs-t

I have a function that manage WFS-T Transaction between a web application client (based on OpenLayers 6) and a GeoServer instance.

```
import axios from "axios";
import { WFS } from "ol/format";
import { FeatureCollection } from "geojson";
import { WriteTransactionOptions } from "ol/format/WFS";
import Feature from "ol/Feature";

const WFSTransaction = (mode: TransactionMode, featuresArray: Feature[]) => {
    const formatWFS = new WFS();
    const xs = new XMLSerializer();
    const options: WriteTransactionOptions = {
      featureNS: "myDomain",
      featureType: "mylayer",
      srsName: "EPSG:4326",
      featurePrefix: "",
      nativeElements: [],
    };
    let node;

    switch (mode) {
      case "insert":
        node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(featuresArray, [], [], options);
        break;
      case "update":
        node = formatWFS.writeTransaction([], featuresArray, [], options);
        break;
      case "delete":
        node = formatWFS.writeTransaction([], [], featuresArray, options);
        break;
      default:
        console.log(
          "passed transaction mode  did not match any of the supported transactions mode"
        );
        break;
    }
    if (node) {
      const wfsNode = xs.serializeToString(node);
      return axios.post(
        `${this._domain}/ows?service=WFS&typeName=${this.fType}`,
        wfsNode,
        {
          headers: { "Content-Type": "text/xml" },
        }
      );
    }
  };
```

Everything is working fine.

**BUT** if I send a feature with some attributes that does not match my table schema in the geoserver store (which is basically a PostgreSQL instance), I got an error message :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows http://meitarimdb:8080/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
<ows:Exception exceptionCode="InvalidParameterValue">
<ows:ExceptionText>No such property: editable</ows:ExceptionText>
</ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

Now the thing is that the property "editable" (that you can see in the error message) is something that I set on purpose and dynamically to the OpenLayers Feature on the flight.

```js
myFeature.set("editable", true);
```

Well if I `unset` this property that I added before sending the transaction, my feature gets updated ...

But this not ideal because for each property that I add dynamically for logical purpose of the application, I have to unset it before sending the transaction. And there is a bunch of them...

So I wonder if there is any options to make the GeoServer more flexible with the properties that I send and simply ignore if a property is not present in the schema, and update those that are presents on the schemas

I did not found in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think there is any way to tell GeoServer to ignore values in a feature, you are expected to provide at least all the non-nullable attributes and none that are not listed in the schema.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In ArcGIS Server I wrote a SOE that could be used as a middleware...do you may be know an equivalent of that in Geoserver ? Also : do you know why Geoserver is so strict with these non schemas values ?

Comment: It's strict because that is what the standard says to do. I'm sure you could write a filter but not adding random attributes to features would be the easy answer

Comment: Thank you for this advice. I personally found the `set` method present in pretty every OL object (including Feature object)   very useful and thats why I add them. But I understand.